# Javascript space function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS code that the function is to validate the form, now what I want to do is add 1 function to prevent space in textbox username with message too, "No space allowed". Here it's my JS code so far :

```
$().ready(function()
    {
        $("#signupForm").validate(
        {
            rules:
            {
                full_name: "required",
                username: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
            },
            messages:
            {
                full_name: "Please enter your full name",
                username:
                {
                    required: "Please enter a username",
                    minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
                },

                password:
                {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                },

                email: "Please enter a valid email address"
            }
        });
    });
```

Anyone can give me idea ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

---

Add a method called noSpace

```js
jQuery.validator.addMethod("noSpace", function(value, element) {
    return !value.match(/\s/g);
}, "Spaces are not allowed");
```

Set it as a rule for username

```js
rules: {
    // ...
    username: {
        // ...
        noSpace: true,
        // ...
    },
    // ...
```

Set a custom message, if you want to override the default message

```js
messages: {
    // ...
    username: {
        // ...
        noSpace: "Username should not contain spaces",
        // ...
    },
```

Comment: I tried the code, the function maybe reversed. When I try to input text without space, it still show the message "Username should not contain spaces". But when I try to space the text, no error message show.

Answer (score 4):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function nospaces(t) {
    if(t.value.match(/\s/g)) {
        alert('Sorry, you are not allowed to enter any spaces');
    }
}
</script>
```

Add following attribute to text input box

```js
onkeyup="nospaces(this)"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("noSpace", function(value, element) { 
    return value.indexOf(" ") < 0 && value != ""; 
}, "No space allowed");

$("#signupForm").validate({
    rules: {
        username:
           {
              required: "Please enter a username",
              minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters",
              noSpace: true
           }
     }
});
```